# IJ.close() - Scripting python in ImageJ/FIJI

Tags: python, jython, imagej

I'm exceptionally new to python/scripting and I'm having a problem. I'm writing the following in Fiji (shortened version of the script is below...)

```
from ij import IJ, ImagePlus
from java.lang import Runtime, Runnable

import os

filepaths = []

for folder, subs, files in os.walk('location/of/files/'):
    for filename in files:
        #the next part stops it appending DS files
        if not filename.startswith('.'):
            filepaths.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(folder, filename,)))   

for i in filepaths:
    IJ.open(i);
    IJ.close();
```

Basically I want to open an image, do stuff, and then close the processed image using `IJ.close()`. However it gives the following error:

`AttributeError: type object 'ij.IJ' has no attribute 'close'`

Any idea how to get around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IJ` class does not have a `close()` method. You probably want to call the `close()` method of `ImagePlus`, which is the class for the image objects themselves.

Try something like:

```
IJ.open(i)
imp = IJ.getImage()
imp.getProcessor().setf(100, 100, 3.14159) # or whatever
IJ.save(imp, "/path/to/myShinyModifiedImage.tif")
imp.close()
```

If you need to operate over multiple slices of a multi-plane image, see also the "Loop over slices" template (Templates > Python menu of the [Script Editor](http://imagej.net/Script_Editor)).

Note also that Jython does not have trailing semicolons on statements.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who is scripting with jython (python in ImageJ/Fiji), the Java docs always help in getting an overview of the modules and their classes/functions:
[Here for example for the module ij](https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/module-summary.html)