# how to control ImageJ from Python 3.4.2

Tags: python, opencv, python-3.x, imagej

I am trying to use Python 3.4.2 to control ImageJ

what I want to do is from python code [,](https://wiki.python.org/moin/) I want to sent orders to imageJ to analayse some images, detecting edges, contrast, noise etc
there is a similar question here
[How to connect ImageJ to python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29749687/how-to-connect-imagej-to-python)
but there is no answer, like "install this, and control the Find Edges button with this command"

I wonder how can I do that, can somebody help me

I have found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27546500/ij-close-scripting-python-in-imagej-fiji), and this [link](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/python-cookbook-2nd/0596007973/ch11s16.html), and they say that it is possible by using "import ij" but there is no ij library that I can use or install.

also ImageJ [website](http://imagej.net/Frequently_Asked_Questions) states in "How can I call ImageJ from my software?" that "If your software is written in another language such as C or Python, there are many ways to integrate Java functionality. You must choose which one is best for your particular requirements." but there are no specifics

this [Google webpage](https://code.google.com/p/py4ij/) says that with "py4ij" I can control imagej with python "Py4IJ - Python for ImageJ - plugin and IDE that allows Python and Jython access to the ImageJ"

but I am not sure how to run it, Help

as an alternative to Imagej is Fiji but I am not sure if python can control it or I have to use [Fiji](http://cmci.embl.de/documents/120206pyip_cooking/python_imagej_cookbook#python_imagej_fiji_cookbook), and [Fiji tutorial](http://www.ini.uzh.ch/~acardona/fiji-tutorial/)

my last alternative is Using [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-get) for image processing but I actually need to use ImageJ or Fiji, so OpenCV is not a valid answer

thanks

**EDIT**

according to the first answer, it suggest to write a CellProfiler's RunImageJ module, but my question is should I have to install CellProfiler? from [here](http://www.cellprofiler.org/interfaces.shtml), following the examples [here](https://github.com/CellProfiler/CellProfiler/wiki/Writing-a-CellProfiler-module) and [here](https://github.com/CellProfiler/CellProfiler) and running the [module](http://cellprofiler.org/CPmanual/RunImageJ.html)

or should I follow the native Python idea from [this link](https://github.com/scijava/scripting-cpython)

in any case the first answer link talks about Jython, but I can not use Jython, the latest version of it is based on python2.7 and I am using 3.4, and there is no development for jython 3.x

help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integration of Python with ImageJ was recently discussed on the new ImageJ forum; see the [Python scripting](http://forum.imagej.net/t/python-scripting/80/3) thread.

While it focuses on calling native-code-wrapped Python modules such as NumPy from ImageJ, the reverse direction (calling ImageJ from Python) is also addressed by some of the solutions, particularly CellProfiler's RunImageJ module. As discussed there, a dedicated programmer could start there and champion a more general solution for the benefit of the community.

In general, this issue is discussed on the ImageJ wiki on the [Python](http://imagej.net/Python) page, particularly the [section on limitations](http://imagej.net/Python#Some_limitations_of_jython).

Comment: if I want to write a CellProfiler's RunImageJ module do I have to install CellProfiler?

Comment: To use CellProfiler modules, yes, you have to install CellProfiler. :-)